# i got sytem error while installing scikit-image

Tags: python, opencv, installation, compiler-errors, scikit-image

I have been triying the install scikit-image but i got errors while installing. I have 64bit ad 32bit python 3.9.13. both of them installed on my computer. Also my computer has 64bit system.

I create a 32bit virtual environment on VSCODE and i want to install scikit-image on there but i got errors about the encountering when trying to install scikit-image in a virtual environment created with x86 Python indicates the same issue as before: a mismatch between the expected x86_64 architecture and the x86 architecture for Python. But when i check my path, ol the paths are okay and when i check my current python system it's 32bit.

could me help about this? Because i have to work on 32bit system.

[I'm sharing my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdfoW.png)

```
    (.venv) C:\Users\osimsek\Desktop\Python\vscode_venv_x86>python -m pip install -U scikit-image
Collecting scikit-image
  Using cached scikit_image-0.22.0.tar.gz (22.7 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [28 lines of output]
      + meson setup C:\Users\osimsek\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9pouxues\scikit-image_959a707540ba4f3d9c6bef5cbffc6d12 C:\Users\osimsek\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9pouxues\scikit-image_959a707540ba4f3d9c6bef5cbffc6d12\.mesonpy-agpxo0eg -Dbuildtype=release -Db_ndebug=if-release -Db_vscrt=md --native-file=C:\Users\osimsek\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9pouxues\scikit-image_959a707540ba4f3d9c6bef5cbffc6d12\.mesonpy-agpxo0eg\meson-python-native-file.ini
      The Meson build system
      Version: 1.2.2
      Source dir: C:\Users\osimsek\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9pouxues\scikit-image_959a707540ba4f3d9c6bef5cbffc6d12
      Build dir: C:\Users\osimsek\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9pouxues\scikit-image_959a707540ba4f3d9c6bef5cbffc6d12\.mesonpy-agpxo0eg
      Build type: native build
      Project name: scikit-image
      Project version: 0.22.0
      Activating VS 17.7.1
      C compiler for the host machine: cl (msvc 19.37.32822 "x64 i?in Microsoft (R) C/C++ Iyilestirmeli Derleyicisi S?r?m 19.37.32822")
      C linker for the host machine: link link 14.37.32822.0
      C++ compiler for the host machine: cl (msvc 19.37.32822 "x64 i?in Microsoft (R) C/C++ Iyilestirmeli Derleyicisi S?r?m 19.37.32822")
      C++ linker for the host machine: link link 14.37.32822.0
      Host machine cpu family: x86_64
      Host machine cpu: x86_64
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-unused-function: NO
      Library m found: NO
      Checking if "-Wl,--version-script" : links: NO
      Program cython found: YES (C:\Users\osimsek\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-egn3taya\overlay\Scripts\cython.EXE)
      Program pythran found: YES (C:\Users\osimsek\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-egn3taya\overlay\Scripts\pythran.EXE)
      Program cp found: YES (C:\cygwin\bin\cp.EXE)
      Program python found: YES (C:\Users\osimsek\Desktop\Python\vscode_venv_x86\.venv\Scripts\python.exe)
      Need python for x86_64, but found x86
      Run-time dependency python found: NO (tried sysconfig)
     
      ..\meson.build:69:14: ERROR: Python dependency not found
     
      A full log can be found at C:\Users\osimsek\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9pouxues\scikit-image_959a707540ba4f3d9c6bef5cbffc6d12\.mesonpy-agpxo0eg\meson-logs\meson-log.txt
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

When i try to install on 64bit python it install easyly and there is not any error.

also i check all requirements list:
`meson-python>=0.14 wheel setuptools>=67 packaging>=21 ninja Cython>=0.29.32 pythran numpy>=1.22 spin==0.6 build .`

Comment: Though there are no guarantees of success, you can try [building the package from source](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/user_guide/install.html#supported-platforms).

Comment: I have tried buildings from sources  but it's not working still i got same error. Thanks for comment. @BRemmelzwaal

Comment: How exactly have you gone about that?

Comment: i start with update my pip than installed the all requirements libraries.  than when i star to install scikit using  'pip install scikit-image' i got error on 'pyproject.toml' file as 'Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.'@BRemmelzwaal

Comment: Meson determines the bitness of the build from the Visual Studio environment. Try to initialize Visual Studio before building scikit-image, e.g. `"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" amd64_x86`. https://github.com/mesonbuild/meson/pull/12393 is required when using clang compiler (required by pythran).